# Create custom widget in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to wordpress, and need to create a custom widget.

I have created a html-form. 
This form contains **actions** to another page and the other page contains php code to show the result.

What should I do to create this widget?

**Code**

```
<form method='post' action="">
<p class="submit">
  <input type="submit" class="button-primary" 
  value="submit" />
</p>
</form>
```

**Onther page 'action'**

```
 <?php
   ob_start();
    .
    .
    .
   $page = ob_get_contents();
   $fp = fopen("output.html","w");
   fwrite($fp,$page);
   ob_end_flush();
   fclose($fp);
 ?>
```

**Process to create widget**

```
class My_Widget extends WP_Widget {

    /**
    * Sets up the widgets name etc
    */
    public function __construct() {
     // widget actual processes
    }

   /**
   * Outputs the content of the widget
   *
   * @param array $args
   * @param array $instance
   */
   public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    // outputs the content of the widget
   }

  /**
  * Outputs the options form on admin
  *
  * @param array $instance The widget options
  */
  public function form( $instance ) {
    // outputs the options form on admin
  }

  /**
  * Processing widget options on save
  *
  * @param array $new_instance The new options
  * @param array $old_instance The previous options
  */
  public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
    // processes widget options to be saved
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who helps me

Comment: To create a widget you need to follow some WordPress core APIs so you can easily learn those from this link [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/series/introduction-to-creating-your-first-wordpress-widget--cms-721) read this from beginning.

Comment: Thanks chamath but  where **action** function form